# Python -0.000000e+00 struct pack return wrong value

Tags: python, data-conversion, python-2.4, struct.pack

Hi I have problem with parsing -0.000000e+00 on linux( on windows is working).

```
struct.pack( "d", -0.000000e+00 )
```

On linux struct.pack change -0.000000e+00 to 0.000000e+00. When i print value before pack is correct but result of struct.pack is like it was 0.000000e+00.

Is there any solution to solve this problem.

I think i need to add negative number witch is closest to 0. How to do that?

EDIT
`struct.pack( "d", -0.000000e+00 )` result '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80'

`struct.pack( "!d", -0.000000e+00 )`result '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

`struct.pack( "<d", -0.000000e+00 )`result '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

`struct.pack( ">d", -0.000000e+00 )`result '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
I want to use "< d" and " > d".

EDIT Sry not error.

Comment: Please post [the code you're using](http://sscce.org/). For this question, the CPU architecture may also be relevant. `struct.unpack('d', struct.pack( "d", -0.000000e+00 ))[0]` works fine on Linux/amd64 with cpython 3.2 and 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The struct format string `"d"` encodes the value in a platform-specific way. Most likely, the platform you decode the bytestring on has a different [endianess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianess) or length of doubles. Use the `!` format character to force a platform-independent encoding:

```
>>> struct.pack('!d', -0.)
b'\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' # IEEE754 binary64 Big Endian
>>> struct.unpack('!d', b'\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')[0]
-0.0
```

Also make sure that you use a supported Python version. In cPython<2.5, struct is known to be buggy. Update to a current version, like 2.7 or 3.2.

Comment: Its not working for me :( Return \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00

Comment: @Luffy Are you absolutely certain that you have used the above code? Can you paste a part of a terminal session to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) or so? And what architecture, Linux distribution, and Python version are you running your tests on? Also make sure that you use `'!d'` to decode as well, and not only to encode.

Comment: Python 2.4.3 I dont knew atm what is architecture. But not common.

Comment: Fortunately, that's enough information. cPython 2.4's struct (and not only that) is indeed broken. You should switch to a Python implementation from this decade.